# How to modify an argument in place and return it in scipy.optimize.least_squares / leastsq?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

Is there any way to use a function that modifies it's arguments in place and then returns them in `scipy.optimize.least_squares` or `scipy.optimize.leastsq` without specifying the Jacobian?
Consider the following example, in which they both fail unless a function computing the Jacobian is provided:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares, _numdiff, leastsq
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

matrix = rng.random((3, 2))
_x = rng.random(2)
vector = matrix @ _x

_fvec = np.zeros_like(vector)


def residuals(x, A, b, fvec):
    np.matmul(A, x, out=fvec)
    fvec -= b
    #return fvec  # Uncomment this line and it fails if jacobian is not provided
    return fvec.copy()

def jacobian(x, A, b, fvec):
    return A


print(least_squares(residuals, np.ones_like(_x), args=(matrix, vector, _fvec)).x)
print(least_squares(residuals, np.ones_like(_x), jac = jacobian, args=(matrix, vector, _fvec)).x)
print(leastsq(residuals, np.ones_like(_x), args=(matrix, vector, _fvec))[0])
print(leastsq(residuals, np.ones_like(_x), Dfun=jacobian, args=(matrix, vector, _fvec))[0])
print(_x)
```

Output:

```
[0.60663577 0.72949657]
[0.60663578 0.72949656]
[0.60663578 0.72949656]
[0.60663578 0.72949656]
[0.60663578 0.72949656]
```

Output (with the line `return fvec` uncommented):

```
[1. 1.]
[0.60663578 0.72949656]
[1. 1.]
[0.60663578 0.72949656]
[0.60663578 0.72949656]
```

It doesn't seem to be possible with `least_squares` as it computes an approximate Jacobian, with `scipy.optimize._numdiff.approx_derivative` which in this case passes it to [_dense_difference](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f990b1d2471748c79bc4260baf8923db0a5248af/scipy/optimize/_numdiff.py#L566) which does stuff like:

```
            f1 = fun(x1)
            f2 = fun(x2)
            df = f2 - f1
```

which will just be `np.zeros_like(x1)` if `f1` and `f2` are the same array. However, `leastsq` seems to just [directly pass it to their wrapper of lmdif from minpack](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/ae026f72fbc3b6c60a5d5b9d2e392b5c1919fd44/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L433) but I don't understand enough fortran/c to know why it also doesn't work here especially considering that in the original implementation of lmdif, the user provided residual function should modify the residuals in place.

Comment: Wanting to support in-place modification of a matrix parameter seems like an anti-goal. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Reinderien I was trying to compare using the scipy wrappers of minpack to using minpack directly, and in minpack the residuals are modified in place so was trying to do the same thing in scipy

Comment: Also, why would this be considered an "anti-goal" when an `out` kwarg is available in pretty much every numpy function to avoid unnecessary allocation of arrays?